# Make divs/text content fixed when screen resolution is changed

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

I know this question has been asked before, and I have researched this, but I think the answer is unique to my situation.

I am designing a web page but I am having a problem. Everything looks fine on my screen and resolution but when I start to zoom in/out (ctrl +-) the formatting of the text gets completely shifted.

I've published the site on my server: 
Based on my code please let me know what the best fix for this would be. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not going to answer this as I hate going to random websites and so on. Create a fiddle of the layout etc and then more people would help. Also "quick fixes" are not good, you want a fix so you don't run into the problem again.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a unique situation. Your css uses a lot of fixed values, ie "margin-top:100px". It is better to use % or automatic margins. Googling "responsive design" should give you an idea on how to fix your site. There is no "quick fix", you need to reformat your website properly if you want it to display correctly on different resolutions/devices.

Comment: Im going to +1 this. Haven't even looked at the site but I can believe it and you even told them what they should do with there website. Seems sensible.

Answer (score 1):

&the containers of your paragraphs have `margin-left` , and when you zoom in/out, it's completely expected to be shifted. if you want to have paragraphs center of the body, you should remove `margin-left` and instead use `auto` for left & right margins.

for example :

```
.introduction { margin:213px auto 0; }
```

if you want to have a container including paragraphs left to another container, use `float` property and give width to each container.

Generally, using container for each section is needed. lots of the problems in your website are because they don't have a block container with proper styles.